# Word for "to put something you earned into a project to make more money"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I forgot the word that means "to put something you have earned into a project to make more money". For example,

> ABC *_*_ its profits into a new venture.

Answer (score 10):

The "standard" terminology is...

> [***reinvest***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinvest) *- to use (money that a business has earned) to improve the business*

But you'll often hear the agricultural metaphorical usage...

> *Like ABC [**ploughed back** its profits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20naughties%20was%20a%20decade%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22ploughed%20back%20its%20profits%22&tbm=bks) into a new venture.*

Comment: Ah, I see.  This is like King Nebuchanezzar demanding from his seers that they not only interpret his dream, but also guess what the dream was.  Nice!

Comment: Well, you now have a starting point. Look up *reinvest* in a thesaurus.

Comment: At least OP posted. If Nebuchadnezzar had been really on the ball, he would have ordered all his seers put to death for not anticipating his question. But I think FF's suggestions are better than the word OP's after anyway.

Comment: @Edwin: Unless someone posts the elusive "different word" (or OP suddenly remembers it and tells us what he was after), we can't really be certain that *reinvest/plow back* are "better" in all contexts. But even so, I'd be pretty sure that any alternatives are *very* much less common than those two. And if I'm honest, the only remotely credible alternatives I can think of (such as *redirected, syphoned off*) all seem to have negative associations, which I rather doubt OP is looking for.

Comment: So you don't believe in seers. I might have known.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't think of that very very elusive word. But thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

They do not imply money that you have earned, but you can also use...

> **expend** - spend or use up (a resource such as money, time, or energy)

Or

> **bankroll** - support (a person, organization, or project) financially

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for "**roll over**":

> I **rolled over** the money from my MegaCorp 401K into a brand-new Fidelity IRA.

Answer (score 0):

*Direct*, in the sense of "regulate the course of":

> ABC *directs* its profits into a new venture.